# IO operation in other thread blocking my UI thread?

Tags: java, android, file-io, mobile

So that IO doesn't block the UI thread in my Android app, I'm trying to move a file write operation into a separate thread. This is the code I'm using to start a low priority thread to write about 1Mb from a byte buffer:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
      try
      {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename));
        try
        {
          final java.nio.channels.FileChannel outChannel = fos.getChannel();
          outChannel.write(byteBuffer);
          fos.getFD().sync();
        }
        finally
        {
          if (fos != null)
            fos.close();
        }
      }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});

t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t.start();
```

These threads are started in my app when certain UI events happen. Unfortunately, I still notice a huge amount of lag sometimes. My UI will freeze for ~2 seconds every 10 or so times I start/finish one of the above threads. If I comment out the thread code, these delays disappear.

**What can I do to stop this IO operation from blocking my UI thread?**

I'm not sure what to do now to diagnose the problem. My understand was that the IO thread would become blocked when "outChannel.write" happened as it was waiting for an IO operation to finish, which would mean my UI thread would immediately take over. Is it the case the write operation actually requires a big chunk of CPU power?

Edit:

With StrictView on (which I'm sure of because it caught some unrelated IO problems in the UI thread that I fixed first), I can confirm no IO occurs in my IO thread.

The results of running traceview are quite puzzling. The UI problem is that, when I'm performing drag and drop actions, every 10 or so times I do this the device seems to freeze for about 0.5 to 1s. The thing you're dragging will freeze and after a delay will eventually jump to where your finger is. In traceview, I kept dragging and dropping until this happened. For the case where this happens in traceview, my background threads aren't running  but there's a sudden block of about 1 second where operations on my UI thread that are usually fast to call are taking about x10 longer to perform. For example, a call to .drawBitmap (with a fixed size bitmap) is shown as taking ~0.2s to execute when every time before this the same .drawBitamp call is taking a tenth of this time. I could just be reading it wrong, but I don't know where to go from here or what to look for.

Comment: It's not the thread per say that's blocking your UI. It's just the OS writing data to the card. File i/o can be slow. Your call to `fos.getFD().sync();` is most likely causing the stuttering.

Comment: So you're saying any write operation I perform will block the UI? What's the point of moving it to another thread then? It still stutters when I take out the .sync but less often. This isn't ideal anyway because then I've no guarantee my file has been written to disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What can I do to stop this IO operation from blocking my UI thread?

The I/O operation is not blocking the main application thread directly. Your code running on the main application thread is blocking the main application thread. You need to determine where your code running on the main application thread is getting tied up. To do this, use a debugger, or `Log.d()` statements, or whatever.

For example, on most Android devices, the filesystem is YAFFS2, which has a per-partition global lock. Quoting [Brad Fitzpatrick](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/b8a52096a866d14e):

> yaffs has a giant lock around the whole filesystem code, so even a tiny stat() can block for seconds if the disk is otherwise being hammered by something else (during boot, heavy sync, etc).

Hence, if you are tying up the filesystem for seconds in your background thread, the main application thread will be unable to do file I/O of its own. Perhaps that is what is tripping you up, in which case `StrictMode` in Android 2.3 can help you identify the source of your difficulty.

> What's the point of moving it to another thread then?

The point is to move the flash I/O off the main application thread. All flash I/O.

FWIW, Android will be appearing on ext4 devices (e.g., Nexus S), and this issue falls away...though you need to then worry about the `sync()` calls. On YAFFS2, `sync()` is less critical, by and large, since it does little buffering.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've edited my question with more info. I'm really stumped now as I've confirmed no IO is going on in my UI thread and traceview appears to show blips of several UI thread function calls that are normally quick to run taking a long time to finish even when the background thread isn't getting CPU time.

Comment: The yaffs lock issue would make sense if the file is on internal storage, but if it's on the SD card?  That's presumably FAT32.  Though if your application is also on the SD card there could be some issue there.  If you have the tools to write a command-line native executable in C, I'd be curious what happens if you create a file writing test and launch it from the ADB shell - will it similarly slow down and android app that's running at the same time?  Actually, no coding needed, you can do it by using cat some_big_file > duplicate in the shell (no 'cp' in default install)